# doxygen ignores classes wrapped in statements

Tags: php, class, doxygen

I'm using doxygen with my php code. Some of my classes are wrapped in if statements in a way similar to this:

```
if(!class_exists('FooBar', false)) {

    /**
     * Docs
     **/
    class FooBar
    {

    }
}
```

doxygen doesn't seem to understand this and ignores `class FooBar` completely. Is there a workaround?

Patching doxygen would be no problem, feel free to suggest how (I guess somewhere in [scanner.l](https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/blob/master/src/scanner.l))

Comment: First of all you should think about why you need such a mess.

Comment: Have you looked at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181896/doxygen-strange-problem-while-documenting-php-if ? The problem is not quite the same as yours but it could give you some ideas for stuff to try out, like adding a `;` at the end of your `if` block.

Comment: @KingCrunch: last time I checked, php threw a "fatal error" when it saw some class declared twice. Crappy language => crappy workarounds.

Comment: @thg435 Its much easier: Don't declare classes twice ... Its not about the language, its about how to use it (and as a side note: _Most_ language breaks, if you try to redeclare identifiers...). To sum it up: Declare every class once _and_ use and autoloader (maybe a custom one). Than you don't have this problems.

Comment: @thg435 how about using namespaces? Its the other way around. Crappy workaround => crappy language (for you). Also it has nothing to do with PHP how doxygen parses it...

Comment: @KingCrunch: thank you for your advice, however, it's not going to work in the context of my project.

Comment: @RonniSkansing: namespaces is not an option for me.

Comment: Cool it with the downvotes guys.  You're supposed to be scoring the clarity and usefulness of the *question* and  **not** the situation (that *none* of us have any information about) that has led to it.

Comment: @Cheeseminer: yeah, php folks always take it personally...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I don't speak PHP I'll offer a possible Doxygen-related answer:

Try surrounding the wrapper components with `\cond` commands that hide code from doxygen.

```
/** \cond */
if(!class_exists('FooBar', false)) {
/** \endcond */

    /**
     * Docs
     **/
    class FooBar
    {

    }

/** \cond */
}
/** \endcond */
```

I am unsure if this will work - it rather depends on the parsing order of Doxygen - but seems worth a try before you start opening the complications that modifying doxygen will introduce.

Comment: Glad to have been able to help, your generous reward notwithstanding.

Answer (score 4):

Doxygen does not interpret your code with its static analysis, therefore the if-clause is just code and the class definition not taken care of for documentation (which also does make sense, as it's only conditional and most likely not needed).

Externalize the class definition so that static code analysis has no problem with it. This class defintion then can be also easily required. It's also compatible with autoloading (not documented in this answer), Doxygen has no problem with it.

```
...

if (!class_exists('Myfile', false))
{
    require(__DIR__ . '/Myfile.php');
}

...
```

**Myfile.php**

```
<?php
class Myfile
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this sounds like a reasonable suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this filter (copied from [GitHub](https://github.com/AbcAeffchen/doxygen-php-filters)):

```
<?php

// Get the input
$source = file_get_contents($argv[1]);
// removes the whole line
list($head,$tail) = preg_split('/.*if\(!class_exists\(.+/', $source, 2);
$openingBracePos = strpos($tail,'{');
$closingBracePos = strrpos($tail,'}');
if($openingBracePos !== false && $closingBracePos !== false)
    $source = $head . substr($tail,$openingBracePos+1,
                             $closingBracePos-$openingBracePos-1);
// Output
echo $source;
```

This filter removes the `if(!class_exists(...))` statement, so doxygen understands the code, without changes in the code itself.

Answer (score 0):

remove the `false`. it's going to work

Comment: What's that supposed to mean?

Comment: class_exists('Myfile') -- try
the second param, the bool, is by default false. It may not be supported at all.

or just delete the class_exist(). The parsing is done once at the start of execution and all classes are recorded, so no risk

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what my question is all about.